# Jumbo frame problem when using switch

Tags: cisco, switch

I have two GigE `cameras`. I use 4 frame per second for capturing. Each frame of first camera is 2.3MB. Each frame of second camera is 1.8MB. So in a second I use 4 * 4.1 = `16.4 MB = 131 Mb of bandwidth`. When I connect each of camera to a computer they work correctly while `jumbo frame` is enabled. When I use a `cisco` switch (SG110D-8) between my cameras and computer, cameras say that maximum packet frame is `1440`. What is the problem? I read data sheet of the switch. It supports jumbo frame.
I note that because of `processing time`, it is recommended that to use jumbo frame (9K).

Comment: Did you configure the switch to use jumbo frames?

Comment: No! how can I do it? my switch is unmanaged.

Comment: You can't for an unmanaged switch. Jumbo frames are non-standard, and each vendor does them differently, sometimes even with the same switch line or even the same switch. Not all switches can be configured for the same size jumbo frames.

Comment: On page 5 of this link << https://media.dustin.eu/media/172104/sg110d-08hp.pdf >> you can see that it supports jumbo frames.

Comment: Is that transfer done as UDP or as TCP? If TCP: What is the TCP MSS being advertised by either TCP speaker to the respective other? Capture and look at the first two data packets of a TCP session (the SYN and SYN ACK packets). Compare in both cases - with switch and without.  Be sure that the DHCP service (if it's there) for the given network segment/subnet does not manipulate MTU in an unexpected way (DHCP option 26).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Excuse me sir. I'm on a project and I forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [data sheet](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/110-series-unmanaged-switches/datasheet-c78-734450.html) the 110 series supports a fixed jumbo size of 9216 bytes.

However, jumbo frames are non-standard and there's no real guarantee that they work. Possibly the camera is simply failing to detect the switch's size. If you can't force the size on the cam or if you do and it doesn't work there's little you can do short of trying another switch.

As a solution to your problem, connect the computer with a dedicated NIC for each camera and you're good. Alternatively, get a 10G switch and a NIC for the computer.